# WordPress mysqli and PDO

Tags: mysql

Does WordPress code base use mysqli or PDO?

I know PDO is superior to mysqli but mysqli is not bad neither. Plus from one of the features of what makes PDO is superior to mysqli ( that is being database agnostic ) does not mean much to WordPress as WordPress  will always use mysql server. But binding params with data types is something PDO supports but mysqli does not and it's a good thing.

My guts tell me that WordPress  does use mysqli but I could not see it in the code base yet.

My second question is if WordPress is using mysqli, is it because of speed concerns or is it because back in the earlier days (when WP was being developed), PDO wasn't just there yet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WordPress uses [`mysql_*` functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php).

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/wp-db.php

It has used those ever since I can remember, which probably answers your last question. It is what I would consider legacy code. I suspect it will be updated sometime soon (those functions were only deprecated as of PHP 5.5, I believe). I don't know which route development will go.

Link to a ticket in Trac, courtesy of Wyck (from a comment below):

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21663

Comment: I checked the code at wp-db.php. On line, 1133, it's got the  db_connect function and according to it, it's not even mysqli. I'm confused. line 1143 clearly has this;  $this->dbh = @mysql_connect( $this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, $new_link, $client_flags );  and according to the PHP manual,  ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php ), this is a mysql code, Not mysqli. Does WP really use mysql ?

Comment: Wordpress uses outdated functions, since `mysql_connect` has officially been depreciated, wp will be moving hopefully to PDO soon (soon is 1-2 years). Ref: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21663

Comment: @AverageJoe ... yes, like I said, WordPress uses mysql functions. Like Wyck, I am hoping for PDO, but I don't know which way it will go.

Comment: Thank you for the trac link Wyck. s_ha_dum please include this link ( http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21663 ) in your answer and correct the grammar where you go "If has used those ever since I can remember," when you get a chance. Thank you

Comment: A little bump. This was written one light year ago.. But today I believe we have mysqli_* in wordpress since some versions, right?

Comment: Okay, did a check of the source code in wordpress now. It's the old mysql* Anyone know the future of the database class in wordpress? Shouldn't be all to hard to include a new alternative mysqli* option and keep the good old mysql* in the background in case - maybe as a catch->if error with new mysqli->run good old db class= plugins etc keep on working

Comment: Thats tels me alot about WP . lol

Answer (score 12):

An update for Wordpress 3.9+ - with PHP 5.5 deprecating the `mysql_*` functions Wordpress has begun using the `mysqli` if it is available on the server. Your future plugins and code should take this into consideration and stop using `mysql_*`. Right now, in 3.9, wordpress checks for the availability of `mysqli` and uses it if available. If not it uses `mysql_*` but that check will be removed at the earliest possible convenience. Down the road it seems they will be using `PDO` but that is a larger project.

Here is an FAQ and announcement on it:

http://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/04/07/mysql-in-wordpress-3-9/